# Lista de números anidadas en CKeditor

Tags: ckeditor

Buen día

Vengo a consultar lo siguiente, implemente ckeditor v4 en un sistema que estoy desarrollando, mi cliente quiere que en el ckeditor pueda hacer este tipo de títulos anidados:

```
1 Titulo nivel uno

  1.1 Titulo nivel dos

      1.1.1 Titulo nivel tres
```

lo que he encontrado hasta ahora en algunos foros es usar el siguiente css

```
    ol {
    counter-reset: item;
}
li {
    display: block;
}
li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") " ";
    counter-increment: item
}
```

Lo he puesto en el archivo donde tengo ckeditor, pero no me ha funcionado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco el tiempo que se tomaron para leer mi consulta, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día, solucione esto dirigiéndome a la carpeta ckeditor/contents.css, luego agregue el siguiente código allí

```
ol {
    counter-reset: item !important;
}
li {
    display: block !important;
}
li:before {
    content: counters(item, ".") " " !important;
    counter-increment: item
}
```

Espero que a alguien más también le sea útil como lo fue para mi.